# PayPal IPN hook isn't called

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I have set the IPN hook to a PHP script on my site using
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-ipn-notify

I have set a return page at

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessmanage/preferences/website

Neither works. IPN is not called, transaction succeeds, but i am not redirected to "thank you" page.

Could you suggest what is wrong?

The page I use for payments at sandbox:
https://market.snowcron.com/cabinet_paypal.php

Comment: Being redurexed or jot has nothing to do with IPN being called or not. Check your IPN log at PayPal for the latter.

Answer (score 1):

This question asks about 2 separate issues

For the IPN issue, check your sandbox IPN history at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_display-ipns-history , and test your IPN listener using the simulator

As for the redirect URL you have set, this only applies to old-style HTML form payment standard integrations. That setting has absolutely no effect for newer API or JavaScript SDK based integrations. Any redirection you wish to perform should be in the `onApprove` javascript function.

Comment: For the second one - thank you. I didn't know. As for the first one: The IPN history is empty (transactions are going through, I can see list of them, but not list of IPN calls). And I am not sure where to look for IPN simulator: I was trying to follow PP's links, but it takes to the non-sandbox simulator, and adding "sandbox" to URL doesn't help. Could you provide a link to a sandbox simulator, please?

Comment: Could you point where the URL for "and test your IPN listener using the simulator" is? I only found one for non-sandbox. Adding "sanbox" didn't help.

Comment: All simulated IPNs are test IPNs, which is the same as sandbox. https://developer.paypal.com/developer/ipnSimulator/